# What are CRF (Conditional Random Field)

Tags: deep-learning, text-mining, nlp, named-entity-recognition, mathematics

Looking for language modeling, I have been finding CRF in a lot of places which is but looking online for the same isn't actually helping me a lot. I referred [Edwin Chen's blog](http://blog.echen.me/2012/01/03/introduction-to-conditional-random-fields/) and [Ravish Chawala's Medium article](https://medium.com/ml2vec/overview-of-conditional-random-fields-68a2a20fa541) but rather than solving my problem, raises more question.

Could you please refer some interesting blog posts, Github repo's or research papers that are going to further help me with this?

Comment: This question is too broad. These two articles do provide a good overview of CRF. re you looking for something specific ?

Comment: I am only looking to understand to implement it. Any blog or GitHub repo would support this. I have updated the question to be more specific. Should I make it even more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stanford CoreNLP is a very good implementation of CRF (In Natural Language Processing domain).

https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.html  . CRF specific implementation is : https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/crf/CRFClassifier.java

Few other resources :

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/08/nlp-guide-conditional-random-fields-text-classification/

https://github.com/lancifollia/crf

https://towardsdatascience.com/conditional-random-field-tutorial-in-pytorch-ca0d04499463